# Base64string manipulated while posting on MVC controller's action method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, base64, image-uploading

I'm getting some image content in `Base64string` format, I'm trying to post that on my MVC controller, but somehow not able to:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "FileUploadWithAjax",
                type: "POST",
                data: 'imageString=' + e.target.result,
                processData: false
            });
```

This is my code to post data on server.

[image]

Data on right side is what I've printed on browser's console, and on left side is the one which I've copied from my controller's action method.

if you see here, wherever there's any '+' sign is replaced with some white space characters.

Am I missing any contentType in ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `dataType` attribute to `text`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "FileUploadWithAjax",
    type: "POST",
    data: 'imageString=' + e.target.result,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'text'
});
```

You might want to check the net console of your browser to confirm where the data is being manipulated.